# Scrapy tutorial xpath code scrapes tables multiple times

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am following the scrapy documentation tutorial and I am looking to scrape sample data from the following site:
http://www.docteur.ch/generalistes/generalistes_k_ag.html

After running the view command in scrapy I get the following html code for the table I am trying to scrape.The page consist of a table for each entry:

```
  <table class="novip">
    <tr class="novip">
      <td class="novip-portrait-picture"
        rowspan="5">
        <a class="novip-portrait-picture"
          href="/medecin/baumberger-hans-rudolf-aarau-5000-medecin.html">
          <img class="novip-portrait-picture"
            src="/customer_controlled/pictures/65903/portrait/65903.png"
            alt="Pas d'image encore"
            onError="portrait_m_image_failover(this)" />
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="novip-left">
        <a class="novip-firmen-name"
          href="/medecin/baumberger-hans-rudolf-aarau-5000-medecin.html"
          target="_top">
          Baumberger&nbsp;Hans Rudolf
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="novip-right"
        width="25%">
        <a class="novip"
          href="/medecin/baumberger-hans-rudolf-aarau-5000-medecin.html"
          target="_top">
          rating info:&nbsp;              <img class="novip-inforating"
            src="/img/general/stars/stars3 "
            alt="rating info"
            width="70" height="14" align="bottom" border="0" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="novip">
      <td class="novip-left">
        Dr. med. Facharzt FMH f&uuml;r Allgemeine Innere Medizin
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="novip">
      <td class="novip-left">
        Bahnhofstrasse&nbsp;92, 5000&nbsp;Aarau
      </td>
      <td class="novip-right-telefon">
        t&eacute;l:&nbsp;062 822 46 28
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="novip">
      <td class="novip-left-email">
        e-mail:&nbsp;
        <a class="novip-left-send-message-button-inactive"
          href="/eintrag/fr_keine_mitteilung_moeglich.html">
          Envoyer un message
        </a>
          &nbsp;
        <a class="novip-left-make_appointment-button-inactive"
          href="/eintrag/fr_kein_termin_moeglich.html">
          prendre un rendez-vous
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="novip-right-fax">
        fax:&nbsp;062 822 35 20
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

For my spider I am using the basics from the tutorial with a custom xpath:

```
def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//tr[@class="novip"]'):
            item = DocteurItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('//a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]/text()[normalize-space()]').extract()
            yield item
```

The output I get in json generates a name Field for every name in the table but populates it with all the names from all tables like this:

```
[{"name": ["Name1, Name2, ..... NameN"] 
[{"name": ["Name1, Name2, ..... NameN"]
```

And so on. How do I have to change the code/xpath so it populates the name field with just one name and then moves to the next table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the expression for the `name` *context-specific* by prepending a dot at the beginning:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//tr[@class="novip"]'):
    item = DocteurItem()
    item['name'] = sel.xpath('.//a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]/text()[normalize-space()]').extract_first()
    yield item
```

Note that I'm using `extract_first()` instead of `extract()` as well.